# What is a Cyclone Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Cyclone Phrase™.

Use the examples below to find the rule. Also find the one error in the chart below. (In other words, one of the phrases below is not really a Cyclone Phrase™.)

| Cyclone Phrases | not Cyclone Phrases |
| --- | --- |
| all alone at noon | by myself at twelve pm |
| blurb in my blog | response on my online journal |
| deerweed and aloe | lavender and honey |
| chic dimple | attractive facial wrinkle |
| it is adjourned | it is suspended |
| adored among guys | loved among men |
| drug and dose | medicine and dosage |
| chug our ale | drink our beer |
| an eerie moon glyph | a strange lunar symbol |
| biotypic fish | fishes of the same genotype |
| bested by my mom | defeated by my brother |
| an old bum begged | an aged vagrant mooched |
| dehorned an elk | remove a wapiti's horns |
| cook and dine | heat and eat |
| an astute moron | a sharp idiot |
| fork, cup, and dish | spoon, knife, and napkin |
| a deformed deltoid | a misshapen shoulder |
| blood and bile | vital body fluids |
| blond belle | light-haired beauty |
| anti and biotic | antibiotic |
| choke a brute | strangle a beast |
| our foul deed | our offensive action |
| cenozoic deluge | paleogene flood |

If you liked this puzzle, try its successors:
[What is a Scalable Phrase™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/what-is-a-scalable-phrase%E2%84%A2)
[What is a Triad Phrase™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16743/what-is-a-triad-phrase%E2%84%A2)

Comment: Deformed deltoid reminds me of Brian Butterfield's "bread and ham deltoids" on his Christmas pizza. Apologies if you've got no idea what I'm on about!

Comment: "Blond belle" is not a Cyclone Phrase™. I can't explain why.

Comment: FYI, "elk" in Europe means moose and not wapiti. But I guess the meanings are irrelevant to the puzzle here?

Comment: @randal'thor good point. I was referring to the North American "Elk" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elk . But it really doesn't affect the puzzle at all, either way.

Comment: This is one of my favorite puzzles on the site! Though I didn't manage to solve it myself, I like that you work your way up with patterns like by looking at the first letters and last letters. The property that rand al'thor guessed incorrectly correlates with the answer, and Julian Rosen almost got there. Rather than starting blankly followed by a (potential) aha moment, you feel a sense of accomplishment as you notice more and more. The negative examples were a good way to rule out the usual silly weak answers, and the paraphrases was funny. I also like the name "cyclone phrase." Keep it up!

Comment: @xnor Thanks for the feedback and compliment. I am glad you enjoyed it!

Comment: If you liked replacing the image with a markdown table, try its successors :p

Comment: @melfnt This one was back in the day, before I realized the huge benefit of providing a text version. I could go back and add that in for all of those word/phrase puzzles, but I think it would be considered trying to bump the puzzles to get upvotes.

Comment: @JLee don't worry, I was joking. Also, in 2015 we did not have support for markdown tables. We started editing the word/phrase (TM) when it was introduced, but it's difficult to spot them all and it takes a long time. It's a good job for the ones seeking for an editing badge though, expecially the "excavator" one

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Each word in a cyclone phrase has

> its letters in alphabetical order if you alternate taking them from the left and right sides. For example: dehorned --> ddeehnor, and adjourned --> addejnoru.
>
>  A cyclone phrase is made of cyclone words only. A word is called a cyclone word because it is in alphabetical order if you go around it like this:
>  [image]

Comment: You are correct. Good job.

Comment: Wait, how is 'old' a cyclone word then?

Comment: @BaileyM: It's the exception JLee mentioned.

Comment: Once again, punished for not correctly reading the question. You are, of course, correct. :)

Answer (score 12):

A Cyclone Phrase™ is one in which

> for each word, the letters in the first half of the word (including the middle letter, if there is one) are in alphabetical order, and the letters in the second half of the word (again including the middle)  are in reverse alphabetical order.
> **Example**:\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}\hline\text{Word}&\text{First half}&\text{Second half}\\\hline \text{all}&\text{al}&\text{ll}\\\text{alone}&\text{alo}&\text{one}\\\text{at}&\text{a}&\text{t}\\\text{noon}&\text{no}&\text{on}\\\hline\end{array}The one exception is "an old bum begged". The word 'old' does not have this property: the first half, 'ol', is not in alphabetical order.

Comment: you're on the right track!

Comment: Hmm...I notice that in every word in a cyclone phrase that has an even number of letters, the letter just past the midpoint comes (weakly) later in the alphabet than the letter just before the midpoint

Comment: Julian, you are an expert at finding another route to solutions! haha! Technically, you have the correct answer here, but can you explain it from perhaps a slightly different angle, one in which "Cyclone" seems to fit?

Comment: Actually, as I think about it more, I'm not sure you've fully discovered the rule... hmm, i'm not sure...

Comment: If it turns out this is not equivalent to your rule, can you give an example of a cyclone phrase that my rule would not consider a cyclone phrase (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Excellent idea. Yes I think I can. Let me see...

Comment: I believe an example of a word that follows your rule but  not the actual rule is "cowed". Also, "abyss".

Comment: @xnor Yes, and there are tons more. The actual rule is a lot more specific. For example, there are 646 6-letter words that fit Julian's rule, but only 61 6-letter words that fit the intended rule. (abound, absurd, accuse, and lots more)

Comment: +1 You were so close, AND you got the one exception, but I cannot give it to you, since Deusovi nailed it (probably with the help of your answer).

Answer (score 1):

A Cyclone Phrase is one that **either**

> contains two words which both have the same letter in the same position (e.g. "**d**rug and **d**ose" or "ch**u**g o**u**r ale")

or

> contains a word in which the same letter appears the same number of places from both the start and the end (e.g. "**b**lur**b** in my blog", "an astute m**o**r**o**n")

or both. The one error is

> "fork, cup, and dish" is not a Cyclone Phrase.

I got to this by wondering why it was called a *Cyclone* Phrase and looking for some kind of circularity or cyclicity in the letters, which led me to the ideas of alliteration and symmetry. Most of the examples have either two alliterative words ("**a**ll **a**lone at noon") or a word starting and ending with the same letter ("**c**enozoi**c** deluge"). From there, finding the actual pattern wasn't too hard.

Comment: Are you considering "ch" as a single letter? Also, wouldn't "beer" qualify "drink our beer" as a Cyclone Phrase?

Comment: ah, rand. you truly are optimized for gathering as many points as possible. perhaps i should optimize myself more like that! whether you have an answer or not, you always seem to post what you have and almost always get points for it. Although, to be fair, your answers are usually good quality, even when not spot on. The points are in answering, not in asking, the questions, right?

Comment: @JLee Partial answers can help others finish off, and almost-correct answers can be popular. And yeah, answer upvotes are worth twice as much as question upvotes. How do you think one gets to nearly 20k? ;-)

Comment: True. Congrats on the 20K points. I did +1 this answer, but it looks like someone down-voted it.

Comment: @JLee The correct answer seems to be a cross between Julian Rosen's and mine, so hopefully this one was helpful to Deusovi!