# What is a Triad Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, english

Now that you are familiar with [Cyclone Phrases™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16219/what-is-a-cyclone-phrase%E2%84%A2) and [Scalable Phrases™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/what-is-a-scalable-phrase%E2%84%A2), let's look at another kind of phrase.

---

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a **Triad Phrase™**.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

(*Warning there may be some spoilers in the comments below this puzzle, so beware*)

[image]

Comment: Can Triad Phrases have any number of words other than two?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes. I just tried to keep the list small.

Comment: Now the question is... can we create a phrase that is a Cyclone Phrase™, Scalable Phrase™, *and* Triad Phrase™? ;)

Comment: @JLee "AID ABBA DIE" :)

Comment: Now this has been solved - why the name 'triad' prhase? Triad implies 3 - while it's a mixed version of two words. Cyclone and Scalable were more clearly tied to the underlying rule..

Comment: @TimCouwelier It is 3 words in one, right? I had other names that fit well too, but they all pretty much gave it away and destroyed the puzzle, making it no fun.

Comment: @JLee 4321 rep - nice one!

Comment: @Alconja Damn, that's nice! [Quickly deletes comment offering 500 rep!] (If you want to hold me to it, I'll be fair)

Comment: @JLee :) Of course not. All in good fun.

Comment: "ambiances" = "mine" + "abacs". You probably meant "abacus", but "ambiances" is no longer a valid word in a triad phrase.

Comment: @JoeZ. How about the plural of [abac](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abac) at Dictionary.com?

Comment: Hmm, that's true.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it this?

> A Triad Phrase™ is one where the alternate letters of each word spell out another word.

peopleless fiacre

> polls/epees & far/ice

poorest friend

> poet/ors & fin/red

schooled stooge

> shoe/cold & sog/toe

Probably called a Triad Phrase™ because

> each word is made up of two other words

Comment: dainty -> dit? rounded -> rudd? Are these words?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dit) and [yes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rudd).

Comment: +1 Great job! I'm curious- how long did you think about this one before solving it, approximately?

Comment: An hour and a half. Initially attempted putting words into sets of three letters each, or in a 3xn grid, to find a pattern. Eventually stumbled upon the solution. Great puzzle!