# How long can two words be if they make up a larger word (challenge)

Tags: word, wordplay, letter-sequence

I came up with this little game. Basically we have to write a word using small caps and big caps so that the small caps write a word and the big caps write a word (in their original order), for example:

STRINginG, the words are STRING and gin. ( or STringING with STING and ring)

MoneY, the words are MY and one.

THEoreM, the words are THEM and ore.

The score of each word is the length of the smallest word.

So STRINginG has score $3$, MoneY has score $2$ and THEoreM has score $3$.

However I do not want to accept the cases in which all the big caps are together. So things like BUTTERfly gentleMAN or CARrot are not allowed.

I would appreciate a lot if you could give me examples of words with high scores (the more the merrier), something especially awesome would be if the words could have related meanings.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When wording a question saying that BUTTERfly is an example of what you are looking for, but that BUTTERfly isn't... is poorly phrased.

Comment: I've created [a similar challenge](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17863/68) with stricter rules.

Comment: 'Course, you could easily make "Stringing" into a 4 with "STringING" - STING and ring.

Comment: oh, that's actually a pretty sweet example

Answer (score 10):

A word with a score of **11**:

> REinstitutionALIZATION

A couple words with a score of 7:

> COUNTERbalanceS
>  LIGHTheartedNESS

Comment: Oh yeah, perhaps it would be better to ask both small and big caps not to be consecutive

Comment: or not, that is fine. Although the more intertwined the better.

Comment: Exactly it seems quite easy with the `-s` suffix.

Answer (score 9):

I have a word with a score of 5

> TrIeNnIaLlY. 
> Made up of the words TINILY and renal with alternating letters.

Comment: Oh, that's high.

Comment: Credit goes to JLee for teaching me this word. I was supremely impressed with the length of the word when I read it in his innovative [Triad Phrase question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16743/what-is-a-triad-phrase™/16749#16749). And the moment I read this challenge, I remembered this fantastic word.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a score of **12**.

The longest non-coined word in the English language is

> antidisestablishmentarianism

It can be split up into

> ANTI disestablishment ARIANISM
>
>  ANTI-[ARIANISM](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Arianism) (12) and [disestablishment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disestablishment)  (16)
>
>  Some examples of the exact word anti-arianism:
>  [An essay on Arianism](http://www.philosophy-religion.org/handouts/pdfs/BERKELEY-DIVINITY-SCHOOL_ATHANASIUS.pdf)
>  [A subject tag](http://petercanisiusmichaeldavidkang.com/tag/anti-arianism/)
>  [The book "The Theological Anthropology of Eustathius of Antioch"](https://books.google.com/books?id=hMoRCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22anti-arianism%22&source=bl&ots=1_7bIRPwQm&sig=PTeyNta6ceAjH95ej0vsCmtPEX0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FBajVfnnNMq0ogSYvpLwDw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22anti-arianism%22&f=false)
>  [The book "Theophilus of Alexandria and the First Origenist Controversy: Rhetoric and Power"](https://books.google.com/books?id=yx95BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22anti-arianism%22&source=bl&ots=fyFp55Bdsi&sig=8jLhF1_YN9sMz_nTtvRarZ-GBAw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FBajVfnnNMq0ogSYvpLwDw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22anti-arianism%22&f=false)

Comment: *Antidisestablishmentarianism* doesn't have a hyphen, but all instances of *anti-Arianism* do (they also include a capital A). I would think this would not meet the expectations of the puzzle because of this.

Comment: @IanMacDonald One option is to verify this opinion with the OP, since it wasn't specified in the puzzle (even before down-voting, maybe  :) )

Answer (score 5):

Submitting two NBA-themed words:

> PACEmakeRs

and

> TRAILblazerS

with a score of **5** and **6**. Although I feel a bit abusing the consecutive caps rule with the simple `-s` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

## Score 8

The highest-scoring word in the Wolfram dictionary is:

> interrelatedness

Which consists of:

> **INTERRE**late**D**ness

and

> interre**LATE**d**NESS**

Found using:

```
n = 8;
wl = ToLowerCase@DictionaryLookup[Repeated[_, {n}]];
wl2 = ToLowerCase@DictionaryLookup[Repeated[_, {2 n}]];
subwords = 
  Cases[Table[
    w -> Select[wl, 
      LongestCommonSequence[w, #] == # && 
        LongestCommonSubsequence[w, #] != # &], {w, wl2}], 
   Pattern[p, _ -> {_, __}]];
Cases[subwords, (w_ -> {___, a_, ___, b_, ___}) /; (Sort[
      Characters[w]] == Sort[Characters[a]~Join~Characters[b]]) :> {w,
    a, b}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess you meant a similar rule for all small caps not being together.
Otherwise you could go with:

> DAYdreamING

with the score of **5** and a word play on your nickname.

Comment: I never knew daying was a word….?

Comment: that example is fine. But DAYING is not a word.

Comment: Me neither, especially not being an English speaker myself. I only found https://www.wordnik.com/words/daying but that might not count as a proper dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> DauntING

or

> PARallelS

which both give a score of **4**

The latter is again a bit controversial as it uses a less common spelling of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele

Answer (score -1):

Here's a score of **16**, if you can accept both words.

> A**ultramicroscopic**SILICOVOLCANOCONIOSIS (38 letters)

### Explanation

The [longest English word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English) that is in a major dictionary is

> Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis (45 letters)

When broken down, that is:

> **Pneumono** ultra microscopic silico volcano coniosis

where the first part, **pneumono**, is a [medical prefix that specifies that the disease is lung-related or pulmonary-related](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/pneumono-).

So, removing it from the 45-letter monster above, we get the word

> ultramicroscopic silicovolcanoconiosis (without the space)

Now, the prefix "a" means "not" (e.g.: atypical means not typical). So, adding the prefix **a** to the word above gives us

> A ultramicroscopic SILICOVOLCANOCONIOSIS
>  That's [ultramicroscopic](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultramicroscopic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=ultramicroscopic) and ASILICOVOLCANO[CONIOSIS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coniosis) (a form of coniosis that is NOT caused by volcano dust or silicon exposure.)

Comment: -1. You can't add "a" to any word you like. I think the questioner meant real words only.

Comment: @Ypnypn Thanks for explaining your down-vote. In your opinion, what makes something a word? Is it being in the dictionary? any dictionary? or being in common spoken use? or being in a medical journal? or being considered real by some organization, such as Guinness World Records, or a Puzzle Club? or what?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I see you have the most up-voted answer on [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232138/add-the-prefix-a-to-various-words) about adding the prefix **a** to words. How does your response apply to coined medical words, like this one? Also, any other thoughts?

Comment: @Ypnypn From what I can tell so far, the prefix **a** can be applied to any word with a Greek origin. So, the question becomes, "Is coniosis of Greek origin?" I do not know.

Comment: +1 for an impressive job defending your answer.  Coniosis comes from konis which is of Greek origin: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pneumoconiosis

Comment: @pacoverflow However ultra- is from latin.  I think negating ultramicroscopic would be macroscopic.

Comment: Arbitrarily adding *a-* is incorrect in many cases; consider *aaaaaultra-*. The opposite of *ultra-* (which means *extreme*) is to simply not have a prefix (*ultramicroscopic* becomes *microscopic*). Aside from all that, however, *silicovolcanoconiosis* does not appear by itself in the dictionary, so your answer to this question does not follow the spirit of the puzzle.

Comment: In any case, wouldn't the prefix there have to be "an-" because of the vowel at the start? "Aerobic", for instance, stems from Greek, and its negation is "anaerobic", rather than "aaerobic" (admittedly not that well-versed in linguistics but I'd assume that's how it would go)

Comment: @pacoverflow yeah i know. that's why i also notified him by replying to his comment on another question.

Comment: @IanMacDonald OK, thanks. Also, the logic behind silicovolcanoconiosis  being a word was that Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis IS a word, and since all the prefixes added seem to exist only to make the rest of the word more specific, then it seems logical to me that we can remove them and still have a valid word, just without the added meaning given by the prefix(es). No?

Comment: @JezW You bring up a great point. I don't have a good reply to it!

Comment: *An-* would be the correct Greek prefix to use for a word beginning with a vowel. Since this particular word contains both Latin and Greek prefixes, the negation may be more correctly *anti-*. However, as I said before, the negation of the prefix *ultra-*, in this case, is to simply remove it.