# Anagrammatical substrings

Tags: wordplay, open-ended

Inspired by [this challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17837/68), I have a similar, with stricter rules.

Find a word that can be decomposed into several other words (more than one). Those words are not allowed to be proper substrings of the starting word. Entries are scored by the length of the shortest word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Comment: @bobble fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Score 8

The highest-scoring word in the Wolfram dictionary is:

> interrelatedness

Which consists of:

> **INTERRE**late**D**ness

and

> interre**LATE**d**NESS**

Found using:

```
n = 8;
wl = ToLowerCase@DictionaryLookup[Repeated[_, {n}]];
wl2 = ToLowerCase@DictionaryLookup[Repeated[_, {2 n}]];
subwords = 
  Cases[Table[
    w -> Select[wl, 
      LongestCommonSequence[w, #] == # && 
        LongestCommonSubsequence[w, #] != # &], {w, wl2}], 
   Pattern[p, _ -> {_, __}]];
Cases[subwords, (w_ -> {___, a_, ___, b_, ___}) /; (Sort[
      Characters[w]] == Sort[Characters[a]~Join~Characters[b]]) :> {w,
    a, b}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Despite the stricter rules, my entry there would be just as valid here.

Here's my word (again) with a score of 5.

> TrIeNnIaLlY. 
> Made up of the words TINILY and renal with alternating letters. And neither word is a proper substring of the original.

**EDIT**:

Inspired from [pacoverflow's answer to the original challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17846/12700), here's a word of score 11 with a small tweak of mine.

> REinstitutionALIZATIONs
> Made up of the words REALIZATION and institutions, with simply the pluralizing 's' at the end for the word institutions, thereby making this fit the new tougher rules.

Comment: *Reinstitutionalization* is not countable, so does not have a plural. Your second suggestion is not a word.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: *Reinstitutionalization* is a noun and can have a logical plural. Consider this usage: Despite repeated reinstitutionalizations, Jack's drug habit is far from over.

Comment: Damn, that word did you right!

Comment: @JLee: Hahaha, all thanks to you for teaching me that word. :-D

Comment: And thanks to SQL database queries for teaching it to me!