# What is a Versatile Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Versatile Word™.

In each of the short, unrelated sentences below, only one of the choices is a Versatile Word™.

The sentences are for context only, and do not affect whether a word is a Versatile Word™.

> 1. She ate a ( **peach / pear** ).
> 2. He ( **boats / sails** ) in the summer.
> 3. She ( **circles / loops** ) around the building.
> 4. He ( **fires / shoots** ) his weapon.
> 5. He ( **aids / helps** ) his sister.
> 6. They wanted to go ( **also / too** ).
> 7. This air always contains ( **dust / ions** ).
> 8. The best ( **coffee / tea** ) comes from India.
> 9. The vet will ( **neuter / spay** ) the cat.
> 10. The gang will ( **loot / raid** ) the store.
> 11. She said ( **bye / ciao** ) and left.
> 12. Only the ( **ash / soot** ) remained.

**What makes a word a Versatile Word™?**

Comment: I'm sad there's no fancy chart this time around.  I suspect it's because indicating which of the words is a Versatile Word™ would make it too easy to solve?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yes, and also, I kinda think people get tired of the same old thing, so I decided to put a twist in it this time. Also, to put it bluntly, the people on this site are amazingly good at solving puzzles quickly, so, I thought this format *might* prolong the solve time a few minutes. :)

Comment: Does the font matter at all?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ No, the font doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Darn. I see there already is a correct answer. >_< I thought it might have something to do with mirroring the text upside-down :P I love these word puzzles! Keep them up!!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I try to make them tricky enough to last a few hours, but I very rarely succeed with these puzzle-solving beasts.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A Versatile Word is:

> A word from which you can remove any one letter and still have a word.

Examples:

```
1. She ate a ( peach / pear ).
```

> Pear: pea, per, par, ear

```
2. He ( boats / sails ) in the summer.
```

> Boats: oats, bats, bots, boas, boat

```
3. She ( circles / loops ) around the building.
```

> Loops: oops, lops, loos, loop

```
4. He ( fires / shoots ) his weapon.
```

> Shoots: hoots, soots, shots, shoos, shoot

```
5. He ( aids / helps ) his sister.
```

> Aids: ids, ads, ais, aid

```
6. They wanted to go ( also / too ).
```

> Too: to, oo

```
7. This air always contains ( dust / ions ).
```

> Ions: ons, ins, ios, ion

```
8. The best ( coffee / tea ) comes from India.
```

> Tea: ea, ta, te

```
9. The vet will ( neuter / spay ) the cat.
```

> Spay: pay, say, spy, spa

```
10. The gang will ( loot / raid ) the store.
```

> Raid: aid, rid, rad, rai

```
11. She said ( bye / ciao ) and left.
```

> Bye: ye, be, by

```
12. Only the ( ash / soot ) remained.
```

> Ash: sh, ah, as

Comment: This is totally right, and it uses a lot of words that I question their existence but I like this answer too much to disagree.

Comment: bingo!  nice job!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for **coffees** / **teas**...  (eas?  tes?  tas?)

Comment: shout out to VictorHenry's hugely understated comment in CodeNewbie's post

Comment: @Goinghamateur Ha. Indeed. Believe it or not, I hadn't yet seen that. He beat me by a good 20 minutes, though.

Comment: @glibdud same here I must have just glazed over it or something...

Answer (score 6):

My best guess:

> With one "elementary letter operation" (shifting one letter to somewhere else), you get a new word.
>
>  *pear* to *aper*, **a** shift to beginning 
>  *boats* to *boast*, **t** shift 
>  *loops* to *sloop*, **s** shift 
>  *fires* to *fries*, **r** shift 
>  *aids* to *said*, **s** shift 
>  *too* to *oto*, **t** shift (dictionary.reference.com had it; dunno) 
>  *ions* to *sion*, **s** shift 
>  *teas* to *east* or *eats*, **t** shift 
>  *spay* to *pays*, **s** shift
>  *raid* to *arid*, **a** shift 
>  *bye* to *bey*, **y** shift
>  *ash* to *has*, **h** shift
>
>  Primary concerns:
>  - *oto* and *sion* are on dictionary.reference.com, but questionable
>  - *too* is paired with *also*, which, if you do a double-connected-letter shift, you get *soal* which works.
>  - For *sion*, the other word *dust* can go to *stud*, but that is a very complex maneuver.
>  Also, I didn't check thoroughly to see if there are other discrepancies.
>
>  Other anagrams off the top of my head for the other words (WA stands for the almighty Wolfram Alpha):
>  - *cheap*
>  - WA says *sisal*...
>  - *clerics*
>  - *sooths* (WA says it is a word, not sure without e...)
>  - WA says *shlep* (I like that word)
>  - *soal* v *oto*
>  - *sion* v *stud*
>  - none for *coffees*
>  - *retune*
>  - *arid* is more elegant a word than *flip* actually...
>  - WA says *icao* is a word...
>  - *otos* I guess
>
>  The only one which is a shift would be icao, which is an abbreviation. So I'm more comfortable with just a one-letter shift.

Comment: This is not it, but it's *kinda* close in a way. No anagrams are used or needed in this puzzle.

Comment: @JLee Aww, and I had just convinced myself that the letter shift worked after researching the weirder ones.

Comment: +1 great idea though. Like I said, you're kinda on the right track in a way.

Comment: circles -> clerics is a great find!

Comment: +1 for "almighty Wolfram Alpha" and +1 for the idea -- this puzzle had me confused :D

Answer (score 6):

I think it might be somewhat similar to a [Triad Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16743/what-is-a-triad-phrase%E2%84%A2/16749#16749). The pattern I've noticed is

> A Versatile Word™ can represent two more words, one starting with the first letter (and omitting the second) and one starting with the second letter (and omitting the first).

Applying the logic to the word list

She ate a ( peach / pear ).

> Pear - par, ear

He ( boats / sails ) in the summer.

> Boats - bats, oats

She ( circles / loops ) around the building.

> Loops - lops, oops

He ( fires / shoots ) his weapon.

> Shoots - soots, hoots

He ( aids / helps ) his sister.

> Aids - ads, ids

They wanted to go ( also / too ).

> Too - to, oo (?)

This air always contains ( dust / ions ).

> Ions - ins, ons (?)

The best ( coffees / teas ) come from India.

> (?)

The vet will ( neuter / spay ) the cat.

> Spay - say, pay

The gang will ( loot / raid ) the store.

> Raid - rid, aid

She said ( bye / ciao ) and left.

> Bye - be, ye

Only the ( ash / soot ) remained.

> Ash - ah, sh (?)

Comment: +1 on the right track! but not *quite* it. All of the words you chose, you chose correctly!

Comment: uhmm, Loops would be loop and oops, not lops and oops.

Comment: I think you can remove any single letter and you'll still have a word.

Comment: @VictorHenry Submit that as your own answer!

Comment: I was thinking along this vein, though you fleshed it out better, I like it.

Comment: @agweber Haha I had to go to a meeting, and besides I'm capped for the day anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Based off of CodeNewbie's insight I have an idea.

> Vowels are quite optional. Versatile words can drop any of their vowels and still be a word!

She ate a ( peach / pear ).

> Pear - par, per

He ( boats / sails ) in the summer.

> Boats - bats, bots

She ( circles / loops ) around the building.

> Loops - lops, lops (Well... that makes sense)

He ( fires / shoots ) his weapon.

> Shoots - shots, shots

He ( aids / helps ) his sister.

> Aids - ads, ids

They wanted to go ( also / too ).

> Too - to, to

This air always contains ( dust / ions ).

> Ions - ins, ons

The best ( coffees / teas ) come from India.

> teas - tes, tas (music and arabic letter?) (dictionary.reference)

The vet will ( neuter / spay ) the cat.

> Spay - spa, spy

The gang will ( loot / raid ) the store.

> Raid - rid, rad (or loot to lot, lot) not happy about this one. Rad is slang, but also unit of radiation dosage... so I think it is legit.

She said ( bye / ciao ) and left.

> Bye - be, by

Only the ( ash / soot ) remained.

> Ash - sh, or soot to sot, sot :/

So I do not believe this is quite correct

> mainly confusion at the repeat letter ones. So I believe 3 are sketchy answers. Might not be right but hope it helps someone.

Comment: even closer! but not quite it! haha this is crazy.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention in the post it runs afoul you saying he picked all of the ones he picked, for example ash.

Comment: For 'spay' it would be 'spa' and 'spy', not 'say' and 'spy' :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is a Versatile Word™ a word that has a homophone? For most of the pairs, only one word has a homophone:

```
    She ate a ( peach / pear ).
```

> pear/pair

```
    He ( boats / sails ) in the summer.
```

> sails/sales

```
    She ( circles / loops ) around the building.
```

> loops/loups

```
    He ( fires / shoots ) his weapon.
```

> shoots/chutes

```
    He ( aids / helps ) his sister.
```

> aids/aides

```
    They wanted to go ( also / too ).
```

> too/two

```
    This air always contains ( dust / ions ).
```

> ions/irons (?)

```
    The best ( coffees / teas ) come from India.
```

> teas/tease

```
    The vet will ( neuter / spay ) the cat.
```

> neuter/nuder (thanks to pacoverflow)

```
    The gang will ( loot / raid ) the store.
```

> loot/lute

```
    She said ( bye / ciao ) and left.
```

> bye/buy (thanks to Going hamateur) ciao/chow

```
    Only the ( ash / soot ) remained.
```

> soot/suit (?)

Comment: bye would also be a homophone

Comment: Dang, you're right.  :/

Comment: neuter and nuder

Comment: Great attempt but this isn't it. It fits without any stretching. Homophones are not needed in this puzzle, although there clearly happen to be a lot!

Comment: Since both bye and ciao have homophones, then logically, this can't be it.