# What is a Self-Absorbed Word™?

Tags: word, pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Self-Absorbed Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Self-Absorbed Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Self-Absorbed Words™,Not Self-Absorbed Words™
CAVE,DEN
GNU,EMU
JACK,JOHN
LAME,HURT
MINT,LEAF
PINE,OAK
WINE,GLASS
Less Common Examples:,
BIRD,BEAR
CURL,BEND
FIJI,EVEREST
LIVES,SOULS
PIPER,FLUTIST
HEART,LUNG
PIP,NOTCH
```

Comment: Haven't you heard of the new big Google project Glass Looks At Someone Smiling? (just kidding). Then there's John Only Has Nine, and Emu Mimics Unix!

Comment: Why the "™" in Self-Absorbed Word™ ?

Comment: @DanWalmsley Because [JLee](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17879/9000) did it and I'm just following in the format they created.

Comment: @JLee Do you remember why you trademarked the words / phrases? Was it just a hook?

Comment: @Engineer Toast Just to make it sound official, I guess.

Comment: @JLee Start an entirely new brand of puzzles. Leave for 7 years. Return. Fantastic.

Comment: @Engineer Toast I'm going through all of the Word and Phrase puzzles for the past 7 years. It is taking HOURS! Glad to be back.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these are

> Recursive Acronyms

I recognize

> Cave Automatic Virtual Environment, Gnu's Not Unix, Curl URL Request Library,  and Wine Is Not an Emulator

Although I'm honestly a little surprised that DEN isn't self-absorbed. I thought I heard of something along those lines once.

Yes, all the self-absorbed words

> Appear on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym)

Comment: /is using GIMP while reading this

Comment: Would it have been more of a challenge had I left out the "Lesson Common Examples" header and just mixed them all up? I was worried it would be too esoteric a puzzle without it but I may have pushed it too far the other way.

Comment: @EngineerToast I don't think that would have made much of a difference? The biggest hint for me was the presence of GNU, which is (to me) by far the most unusual word on the list.

Comment: @EngineerToast Yep, as soon as I saw "GNU" I didn't really even need to look at the rest of the list.  Take out that word and it would be much more challenging.

Comment: @Sconibulus To think, here I left it in *specifically* to make sure it wasn't too challenging. Ah, well. There'll be a new one tomorrow.

Comment: According to Douglas Hofstadter, GOD is one of these, too. It stands for GOD Over Djinn.