# A 5 letter word that remains a word if you remove any one letter

Tags: word

I'm interested in finding English words that, when any one letter is removed, the result is still a valid, correctly-spelled English word. For example, the word "SPAY" is an example of such a word, as "PAY" "SAY", "SPY", and "SPA" are also words. I have an example of a five-letter word, but I'm interested to see what others come up with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for

> [A versatile word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17879/41566). That post contains several examples such as BOATS and LOOPS. A 6 letter example is also given: SHOOTS.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if there are any 6 letter examples?

Comment: @TheoBendit updated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code to identify all such words, using the [CSW21](https://scrabbleplayers.org/w/SOWPODS) Scrabble lexicon as my dataset. The longest such word is six letters long; all five and six-letter examples are bolded in the list below.

> AAH
> AAHS
> AAL
> AALS
> AAS
> ABA
> ABAS
> ABY
> ABYS
> AGAS
> AHA
> AHI
> AHIS
> AID
> AIDS
> AIN
> AINS
> AIS
> AIT
> AITS
> ALA
> ALAS
> AMA
> AME
> AMI
> ANA
> ANAS
> ANE
> ANIS
> ANY
> ARE
> ASH
> ATE
> AWE
> AYE
> BAA
> BAAL
> **BAALS**
> BAAS
> BAE
> BAY
> BAYE
> **BAYES**
> BAYS
> BEE
> BEEN
> BIO
> BIOS
> BOAR
> **BOARS**
> BOAT
> **BOATS**
> BOI
> BOIS
> BOO
> BOOH
> **BOOHS**
> BOON
> BOOR
> BOOS
> BOOT
> **BOOTS**
> BORA
> BOY
> BOYS
> BROO
> **BROOS**
> BYE
> BYES
> **COOMS**
> COON
> **COONS**
> COOP
> **COOPS**
> COOS
> COOT
> **COOTS**
> DAE
> **DEARN**
> **DEARNS**
> DEE
> DEEN
> DOE
> DOO
> DOOM
> **DOOMS**
> DOON
> DOOR
> DOOS
> EAN
> EANS
> EAR
> EARS
> EAS
> EAT
> EEL
> EEN
> EEW
> EME
> ENE
> ERAS
> ERE
> EST
> ETA
> EWE
> FAA
> FAAS
> FAE
> FAY
> FEE
> FEEN
> FOUR
> FRAY
> GIO
> GIOS
> **GLEED**
> GOAT
> GOO
> GOON
> **GOONS**
> GOOR
> GOOS
> HAE
> HAM
> **HAUNT**
> **HEARD**
> **HEARDS**
> HEM
> HMM
> HMMM
> HOE
> HOES
> HOI
> HOIS
> HOM
> HOO
> HOON
> HOOP
> HOOT
> ION
> IONS
> IOS
> ISO
> KAI
> **KAINS**
> KAIS
> KAY
> KOI
> KOIS
> **LEAST**
> LEAT
> **LEATS**
> LEEK
> LOO
> LOOP
> **LOOPS**
> LOOR
> LOOS
> LOOT
> **LOOTS**
> LOUD
> LOUR
> MAA
> MAAS
> MAE
> MAM
> MANA
> **MANAS**
> MAY
> MEE
> MEM
> MMM
> MOAT
> **MOATS**
> MOE
> MOES
> MOI
> MOIL
> MOM
> MOO
> MOON
> **MOONS**
> MOOP
> **MOOPS**
> MOOR
> MOOS
> MOOT
> **MOOTS**
> MOU
> MOUS
> MOY
> MUM
> MUMM
> NAE
> NAY
> NAYS
> NEE
> NOO
> NOON
> NOY
> NOYS
> NYE
> OBE
> OBES
> OBI
> OBIS
> OBO
> OBOS
> ODE
> OES
> OHM
> OHO
> OIS
> ONE
> ONO
> ONOS
> ONY
> OOF
> OOH
> OOHS
> OOM
> OOMS
> OON
> OONS
> OOP
> OOPS
> OOR
> OOS
> OPE
> OPES
> ORE
> ORES
> OUDS
> OUP
> OUPS
> OUR
> OUS
> OWE
> OYE
> OYES
> **PAINS**
> **PAIRS**
> PAWN
> **PAWNS**
> PEA
> PEAN
> **PEANS**
> PEAR
> PEAS
> PEAT
> **PEATS**
> PEE
> PEEL
> **PEELS**
> PEEN
> PERE
> PEST
> PHOT
> POI
> POIS
> POO
> POOH
> **POOHS**
> **POONS**
> POOP
> **POOPS**
> POOS
> POOT
> **POOTS**
> **POWNS**
> PREE
> PROO
> **PROOF**
> RAID
> **RAIDS**
> RAIN
> RAIT
> **RAITS**
> REE
> REEN
> ROOM
> **ROOMS**
> ROOT
> **ROOTS**
> SAIM
> **SAIMS**
> SAIN
> **SAINS**
> SAIR
> **SAIRS**
> **SARIS**
> SEAN
> **SEANS**
> SEAR
> **SEARS**
> SEAT
> SEEL
> **SEELS**
> SEEN
> SHAY
> SHO
> **SHOOT**
> **SHOOTS**
> SIT
> **SKEEN**
> **SNEED**
> SOH
> SOUP
> **SOUPS**
> SOUS
> **SPARED**
> SPAY
> SYEN
> TAE
> TAI
> TAIN
> **TAINS**
> TAIS
> TAIT
> **TAITS**
> **TARES**
> TASK
> **TASKS**
> TEA
> TEAS
> TEAT
> **TEATS**
> TEE
> TEEL
> **TEELS**
> TEEN
> TOE
> TOO
> TOOM
> TOON
> TOOT
> **TORES**
> **TREES**
> UMM
> WAIN
> **WAINS**
> WAIS
> WAIT
> **WAITS**
> WARY
> WEE
> **WEELS**
> WEEN
> WOE
> WOO
> WOOF
> **WOOFS**
> WOON
> **WOONS**
> WOOS
> WOOT
> YAE
> YEA
> YEAR
> **YEARD**
> **YEARDS**
> YEAS
> YOU
> YOUK
> **YOUKS**
> ZEA
> ZEE
> ZOO
> ZOOS

The only six-letter words here are **DEARNS**, **HEARDS**, **SHOOTS**, and **SPARED**.

Answer (score 0):

Bread
Read
Bead
Bred
Brea
I checked out Brea and it seems to be a word, although Scottish I think.

Comment: What about "Brad"? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that's a word.

Comment: @F1Krazy:  a brad is a small nail or a brass fastener for holding sheets of paper together.

Comment: I don't see how this adds to the first answer posted here - the word this has its shorter than the longest there.