# What is an Efficient Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, english

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it an **Efficient Phrase™**.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

[image: Efficient Phrases and Not Efficient Phrases]

---

If you liked this puzzle, try others like it:
    [What is a Cyclone Phrase™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16219/what-is-a-cyclone-phrase%E2%84%A2)
    [What is a Scalable Phrase™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/what-is-a-scalable-phrase%E2%84%A2)
    [What is a Triad Phrase™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16743/what-is-a-triad-phrase%E2%84%A2)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An Efficient Phrase™ is one where

> each of its letters can be drawn as a single line, without lifting the pen or retracing your path. This allows the letters `BCDGIJLMNOPSUVWZ`. This limits the word more than it might seem because the three most common letters `ETA` are disallowed.

Comment: The only problem is that you can write "E", "T", and "A" without lifting your pen. You have to retrace your line though.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Retracing could be considered "not efficient".

Comment: Fair enough, I'll give you that.

Comment: You draw your A's different than I do, as I have no need to lift my pen. Also they look like stars missing a leg.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it's that an 'E'fficient Phrase<sup>tm</sup> has

> no 'ETA' (estimated time of arrival).

Though I would have thought the opposite to be true.

Also,

> the full list of letters that are missing are: AEFHKQRTXY, which, when rearranged, gives us TRAHKXEFQY*, a common antonym of "efficient".
>  <sub>**not a word*</sub>